# How do the miners prove to have actually run the contract code that they claim the gas fees for?

Tags: mining, contract-design, proof-of-work, ethash

How is the fact of execution of the contract bytecode in the VM proven by the miner?
Why can't a miner just say "uhm, the contract didn't do anything so I take all the gas"?

Comment: you will find some resonpse elements here : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3421/smart-contract-consensus-for-dummies

Comment: Good find. That's the one I was thinking of :-)